# Instructables open source code: Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I've seen this error on several other questions but couldn't find the answer.
{I'm a complete stranger to Python, but I'm following the instructions from a site and I keep getting this error once I try to run the script:

IndexError: list index out of range

Here's the script:

```
##//txt to stl conversion - 3d printable record
##//by Amanda Ghassaei
##//Dec 2012
##//http://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Printed-Record/
##
##/*
## * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
## * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
## * the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
## * (at your option) any later version.
##*/


import wave
import math
import struct

bitDepth = 8#target bitDepth
frate = 44100#target frame rate

fileName = "bill.wav"#file to be imported (change this)

#read file and get data
w = wave.open(fileName, 'r')
numframes = w.getnframes()

frame = w.readframes(numframes)#w.getnframes()

frameInt = map(ord, list(frame))#turn into array

#separate left and right channels and merge bytes
frameOneChannel = [0]*numframes#initialize list of one channel of wave
for i in range(numframes):
    frameOneChannel[i] = frameInt[4*i+1]*2**8+frameInt[4*i]#separate channels and store one channel in new list
    if frameOneChannel[i] > 2**15:
        frameOneChannel[i] = (frameOneChannel[i]-2**16)
    elif frameOneChannel[i] == 2**15:
        frameOneChannel[i] = 0
    else:
        frameOneChannel[i] = frameOneChannel[i]

#convert to string
audioStr = ''
for i in range(numframes):
    audioStr += str(frameOneChannel[i])
    audioStr += ","#separate elements with comma

fileName = fileName[:-3]#remove .wav extension
text_file = open(fileName+"txt", "w")
text_file.write("%s"%audioStr)
text_file.close()
```

Thanks a lot,
Leart

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's because the list you are accessing is getting accessed beyond it's length. I would recommend, going line by line to debug the code and read what @Pynchia has posted on the comment above, before asking any more questions.

Comment: I really have no idea how the code works, so I'm afraid I'll get it all messed up before I post it here! The error comes in this line: 
 frameOneChannel[i] = frameInt[4*i+1]*2**8+frameInt[4*i]#separate channels and store one channel in new list

Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leart - check these it may help:

1. Is your input file in correct format? As I see it, you need to produce that file before hand before you can use it in this program... Post that file in here as well.
2. Check if your bitrate and frame rates are correct
3. Just for debugging purposes (if the code is correct, this may not produce correct results, but good for testing). You are accessing frameInt[4*i+1], with index i multiplied by 4 then adding 1 (going beyond the frameInt index eventually).
   Add an 'if' to check size before accessing the array element in frameInt:
   if len(frameInt)>=(4*i+1):
   Add that statement right after the first occurence of "for i in range(numframes):" and just before  "frameOneChannel[i] = frameInt[4*i+1]*2**8+frameInt[4*i]#separate channels and store one channel in new list"

*watch tab spaces